# jQuizMe - Multilist answers arrange

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuizMe to prepare a questionnaire, one problem I have is that listing the answers for Multilist questions if the correct answer is all of the above.
Here is my script:

```
multiList: [
               {
                 ques: "The answer is:",
                 ans: "All of the above",
                 ansSel: [Answer 1","Answer 2","Answer 3","Answer 4" ]
               }
```

The answers are displayed as:

```
Answer 1
Answer 2
All of the above
Answer 3
Answer 4
```

I would like to display it as:

```
Answer 1
Answer 2
Answer 3
Answer 4
All of the above
```

I would appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Insert a `null` where you want the answer in the list. In your case it will be at the end.

**JSFiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/qWjBq/

**HTML**

```
<div id="quiz3"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function ($) {
    var quiz3 = {
        multiList: [{
            ques: "Question1?",
            ans: "All of the above",
            ansSel: ["Answer 1", "Answer 2","Answer 3", "Answer 4",null ]
        }]
    };
    $("#quiz3").jQuizMe(quiz3);
});
```